# ¿Es "haber de" el origen del futuro simple en español?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, historia, futuro

En el DPD se explica el uso de [haber de + infinitivo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=phjmVDAG4D6WPVG3Nr) cuando se usa para hablar del futuro:

> ... A veces expresa, simplemente, acción futura: «¡No he de morir hasta enmendarlo!» (Cuzzani Cortés [Arg. 1988]);

Las terminaciones que tenemos para formar el futuro son muy parecidas a las del verbo haber:

- Comeré, comerás, comeremos
- He de comer, has de comer, hemos de comer
- Comer h[e], comer h[as], comer h[emos]

¿Es posible qué este uso del "haber" para denotar futuro sea el origen de la terminación que tenemos para el futuro simple, o es coincidencia?

Comment: Parece que sí, al menos en varios sitios así lo dicen: http://eljuego.free.fr/Fichas_gramatica/FG_futuro.htm. Será  cosa de buscar fuentes más oficiales

Comment: Definitivamente sí.  Es uno de los ejemplos más claros (digo yo) de la gramaticalización, ya que se ve todas los eslabones de la cadena o gradiente de gramaticalización, desde *haber* como palabra de significado normal, a ser palabra de carácter gramatical, a ser cliítico, y finalmente a ser afijo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, es conocido que el tiempo futuro actual se originó a partir de la forma "indicativo + haber". En la Wikipedia en inglés [se nos cuenta que](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense#Future_tense_with_habere) (traducción):

> Aunque el latín clásico usaba sufijos verbales para expresar el futuro, el latín vulgar adoptó el uso de *habere* con el infinitivo, como por ejemplo:
>
> > *petant aut non petant venire habet* (lo quieran o no, vendrá)
>
> De esta construcción se derivan los tiempos simples futuros de la mayoría de lenguas romances. Conforme el verbo auxiliar fue perdiendo fuerza (de un verbo que expresaba obligación, deseo o intención a un simple marcador de tiempo), perdió también su autonomía sintáctica (convirtiéndose en un enclítico) y su sustancia fonológica.
>
> Así, la secuencia en latín vulgar *amare habeo* dio origen al *aimerai* francés, al *amaré* español, etc.

También, en la primera gramática de la RAE, compuesta en 1771, podemos leer:

> [...] debe advertirse que el futuro de indicativo, y la segunda terminacion del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo, que hoy son tiempos simples, parece que se usaron en lo antiguo como compuestos, y si no lo eran, tenían á lo menos la singularidad de partirse, y admitir en medio algún pronombre.
>   A favor de la composicion hay varios lugares de nuestras leyes, crónicas, y escrituras antiguas.

A partir de aquí muestra los siguientes ejemplos:

- *Lo que oistes en poridad predicarlo hedes sobre los tejados.*
- *Mientra que yo pueda, facerlo he asi.*
- *E yo librarlo he como tuviese por bien.*

Y explica que "predicarlo hedes" (o "habedes") equivale a "predicaréis", y que "facerlo de" y "librarlo he" equivalen, respectivamente, a "lo haré" y "lo libraré". Concluye así:

> [...] y de todos tres exemplos se puede inferir verosimilmente la composicion del futuro de indicativo con el verbo principal y el auxiliar *haber*.

Me ha resultado curioso que, en esta primera gramática de la RAE, se considera que el futuro compuesto de indicativo es "he de amar", mientras que "habré amado" y "hubiere amado" son los futuros compuestos de subjuntivo.

En todo caso, en los albores del español este cambio ya estaba completado. Al menos en el siglo XIII ya se escribía el futuro simple de indicativo con la forma actual (negritas mías):

> *Yo sso el pan biuo que desçendí del çielo, e qui comiere deste pan **biurá** por ssienpre; et el pan que yo **daré** es mi carne por vida del mundo; et non **sserá** esto commo uuestros padres, que comieron la magna en el desierto e murieron, mas este pan que uos yo do es cutiano por ssienpre iamás.*
>
> Alfonso X, "Setenario", c1252-1270 (España)

E incluso en el siglo XII:

> *Pues esso queredes, Cid, a mí mandedes ál:
>
>   dadme ciento e treinta cavalleros pora huebos de lidiar,
>
>   cuando vós los fuéredes ferir, **entraré** yo del otra part;
>
>   o de amas o del una Dios nos **valdrá**.*

La forma que prevaleció hasta más tarde fue, como indica la primera gramática, la del futuro en forma de "infinitivo + haber" con pronombre intermedio, e incluso mezclado con el futuro actual: *"...et yo averé fuego et echarlo he aí en la leña..."* (anónimo, 1251).

Comment: Nota que los nombres de los tiempos han variado, por lo que cuando dice «futuro compuesto», no se debe contemplar como equivalente de lo que hoy llamamos el futuro compuesto.

Comment: @guifa pero en aquella primera gramática sí se dice claramente que "habré amado" era la forma de subjuntivo. Podría ser una pregunta curiosa tratar de averiguar cuándo pasó a ser de indicativo y por qué se consideraba subjuntivo por aquel entonces.