# ¿Cuándo pasó el tiempo "habré amado" a formar parte del modo indicativo?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, historia, rae, futuro

En la investigación para [mi respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22600/12637) a *[¿Es "haber de" el origen del futuro simple en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22595/12637)* descubrí que en la primera gramática publicada por la RAE se tenía que el futuro compuesto del indicativo era *he de amar*, mientras que *habré amado* y *hubiere amado* eran los tiempos futuros compuestos del subjuntivo.

Me llamó la atención este detalle, por lo cual pregunto:

- **¿Se entendía entonces (siglo XVIII) el tiempo *habré amado* de forma diferente a como se hace ahora, para justificar su inclusión en el modo subjuntivo?**
- **¿Cuándo consideró la RAE que el tiempo *habré amado* debía pasar del modo subjuntivo al indicativo? ¿Qué razones dio?**

Como pista para resolver esta duda, comentar las diferencias que existen entre la definición actual del *modo subjuntivo* y la de 1771:

- Actual: "modo con que se marca lo expresado por el predicado como información virtual, inespecífica, no verificada o no experimentada".
- Antigua: "el que necesita juntarse con otro verbo expreso ó suplido que perfeccione el sentido de la oración".

Es decir, se consideraba que el tiempo "habré amado" no podía ir solo en una oración, y que siempre debía ir acompañado de otro verbo (ya sea de forma explícita o implícita). Pone la primera gramática los siguientes ejemplos:

> Justo es que yo *ame* á quien me ama.
>   Yo *escribiria* si pudiese.

En estos ejemplos se ve que una frase que sea simplemente "yo ame" o "yo escribiría" queda como incompleta (nótese que el tiempo "escribiría" se consideraba entonces [parte del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22067/12637)). ¿Es esto así? ¿Realmente el actual futuro compuesto de indicativo no podía ir solo en una oración en el siglo XVIII?